# Fill other columns with missing dates Nan Pandas DataFrane

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am actually extracting data from several excel files monitoring my daily calorie intake. I managed to use list comprehension to generate the dates. I tried to use merge or join and it does not work.
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns.

```
date_list = ['2021-05-22','2021-05-24','2021-05-26','2021-05-27']
idx = pd.date_range(date_list[0], date_list[-1]) # To find missing dates
df_dates = pd.DataFrame(idx) # To convert list to DataFrame
df1_dates = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df_dates.values,2,axis=0)) # However, there is no column title and it is default at 0.
```

I have another set of data with my calorie intake and exercise minutes.

```
# These are Lists.
Time = [Morning, Afternoon, Morning, Afternoon, Morning, Afternoon, Morning, Afternoon]
Calories = [420,380,390,400,350,280,300,430]
Duration = [50,40,45,50,45,50,44,58]
```

The problems I am facing is that I don't know how to create a column title ('Date') for df1_dates dataframe after using np.repeat. I want to fill the other columns that corresponds to the missing dates with 'NaN'.

The output should look something like this:

```
         Date       Time calories duration
0   22/5/2021    Morning      420       50
1   22/5/2021  Afternoon      380       40
2   23/5/2021    Morning      Nan      Nan
3   23/5/2021  Afternoon      Nan      Nan
4   24/5/2021    Morning      390       45
5   24/5/2021  Afternoon      400       50
6   25/5/2021    Morning      Nan      Nan
7   25/5/2021  Afternoon      Nan      Nan
8   26/5/2021    Morning      350       45
9   26/5/2021  Afternoon      280       50
10  27/5/2021    Morning      300       44
11  27/5/2021  Afternoon      430       58
```

Comment: You can declare the column names within the constructor: `pd.DataFrame(..., columns=[xxx])`. Another option is to set column names like this: `df1_dates.columns = [xxx]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your dataframe with existing data and reindex it with missing dates

```
# Input data
date_list = ['2021-05-22','2021-05-24','2021-05-26','2021-05-27']
calories = [420,380,390,400,350,280,300,430]
duration = [50,40,45,50,45,50,44,58]

# Dataframe with sparse index
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.to_datetime([d for d in date_list]),
                                  ["Morning", "Afternoon"]],
                                 names=["Date", "Time"])
df = pd.DataFrame({'calories': calories, 'duration': duration}, index=idx)

# Dataframe with full index
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range(date_list[0], date_list[-1]),
                                   ["Morning", "Afternoon"]],
                                  names=["Date", "Time"])
df1 = df.reindex(idx1).reset_index()
```

```
>>> df1
         Date       Time  calories  duration
0  2021-05-22    Morning     420.0      50.0
1  2021-05-22  Afternoon     380.0      40.0
2  2021-05-23    Morning       NaN       NaN
3  2021-05-23  Afternoon       NaN       NaN
4  2021-05-24    Morning     390.0      45.0
5  2021-05-24  Afternoon     400.0      50.0
6  2021-05-25    Morning       NaN       NaN
7  2021-05-25  Afternoon       NaN       NaN
8  2021-05-26    Morning     350.0      45.0
9  2021-05-26  Afternoon     280.0      50.0
10 2021-05-27    Morning     300.0      44.0
11 2021-05-27  Afternoon     430.0      58.0
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, thank you for your answer! So I shouldn't use np.repeat?

Comment: You needn't `np.repeat`. `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` create all combinations from `Date` and `['Morning', 'Afternoon']` (<= length is 2 as `np.repeat`). Display `idx` and `idx1` to see the structure of MultiIndex

Comment: Don't forget to accept the response if it fit your needs.

Comment: It should be df1 = df.reindex(idx).reset_index() instead of idx1 right!

Comment: No the opposite, It should be `idx1` instead `idx`. Fixed it.

Comment: Ok last question! I tried exporting this to an excel file using df1.to_csv(...), however, the NaN values on the dataframe appeared to be an empty cell on excel. How do I make it display NaN on the excel sheet?

Comment: convert those nan's to string i.e `df=df.fillna('NaN')`

Comment: How do you convert the NaN's to string!

Comment: by filling them with string i.e `df=df.fillna('NaN')`

Comment: Cool that works! Thanks Corralien for the great help!!! thaks anurag!

Comment: Keep your dataframe as is and when you export it to Excel with `pd.to_excel` use parameter `na_rep='NaN'` (or whatever value): `df1.to_excel('myfile.xlsx', na_rep='NaN')`